# Notepad++ with "sub levels"

Tags: notepad++, html, syntax-highlighting

I am writing HTML in Notepad++, but I did not find a way of making it more organized. I want, for example, that "head" is more to the right than "html".

Example:
Notepad++ is like:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/LaSoc1u.png]

And i want it to be like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD85o.png]

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something to auto-indent your code.

Say you have:

```
<html>
<head>
<div>test</div>
</head>
</html>
```

copy and paste to https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/ and click beautify to auto-indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

That is [Haml](http://haml.info/) it's a markup language for HTML, Notepad++ does not convert HTML to Haml.

If you are using Notepad++ to view Haml format files to highlight the syntax you will need to download and use a [haml syntax highlighting](https://github.com/cemrich/haml-notepad-plus-plus).

Here is a superuser question previously asked regarding [Notepad++ auto indention](https://superuser.com/q/1051404/907112).

Comment: Not EXACTLY like that one, but with "sublevels".

Comment: and also, i dont know how to install that haml syntax highlighting. Im a noob on this stuff

Comment: @PatrickFeeney [link](https://github.com/cemrich/haml-notepad-plus-plus#how-to-use) explains how to download and import it into Notepad ++. In relation to organising HTML it all depends on the coder, have a look at [link](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_syntax.asp).

Comment: Well...thanks, but i meant to the "order"(sub levels?), not to the color of the code.

Comment: For example, I want <body> more to the right than <html>.

Comment: @PatrickFeeney use indentation by pressing the Tab button on your keyboard.

Comment: only way???REALLY :(

Comment: @PatrickFeeney I've updated my answer with a link to a previous Superuser question regarding Notepad++ auto indention.